# How can I detect whether visitor comes to mywebsite from PPC(google ads)

Tags: php, ads, adsense, powerpc

I am trying to implement logic in my website to identify if visitor comes from google ads. I am not sure how can I be sure that visitor comes at WellVine through google email.

What are the logic to detect visitor comes from google ads?

Please let me know if you have any idea/logic on my above query.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the following query parameter is present in your url:
`gclid` using `$_GET['gclid']`

**For example:**

```
if (isset($_GET['gclid'])) {
    // you have a google ads visitor!
}
```

**Further details on what the `gclid` parameter represents:**

*Gclid is a globally unique tracking parameter (Google Click Identifier) used by Google to pass information back and forth between Google AdWords and Google Analytics.*